# SSIS Incremental Data Load

Tags: ssis

I am trying to do an incremental data load from one table to two other tables. Right now I have two Execute T-SQL Statements using INSERT INTO...SELECT statements to populate the destination tables. I would like to find a way to run the data load tasks only for new rows added since the last package execution. My current approach is I am trying to figure out how to obtain the timestamp for last package run, store it as a package-scoped variable, and then modify the INSERT INTO...SELECT statements to filter the records with timestamps > the last package execution timestamp. Does anyone know the best way to go about this, does anyone know if or where SSIS keeps the timestamp for a package's last execution run?

Comment: SQL Server offers [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322(v=sql.110).aspx) for this. Instead of an inaccurate timestamp, you get all changes after a specific database version from the database itself. This is available in all supported versions and editions. You can specify what gets captured (eg only key values and change reason ie `I`,`D`,`U`) and how long the changes are kept. No schema changes are necessary

Comment: Another approach I'm thinking is to create a timestamp column in the database that records the last time a record was inserted or modified.

Comment: You *don't* need to to that. That was replaced by change tracking. The database *already* has that infrastructure built-in. You only store the last update version and ask for changes since that version. You don't need to add the timestamp columns and triggers because the database *already* does that for you.

Comment: Besides, how are you going to track *deletions* with timestamps?

Comment: All you have to do to get modified row is a simple join eg `FROM Sales.Customer JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES Sales.Customer, @theVersionISavedFromTheLastUpdate) CT ON CT.[CustomerId] = Sales.Customer.[CustomerId]` to get inserted/updated rows or `RIGHT JOIN ` to get deleted keys as well.